# How to categorize this

Tags: design-patterns

Which design pattern would best fit the following:

Object has collection of sub objects which all implement the same interface as the parent object. The parent object iterates over all child objects interface method.

Could it be any of the following:

- delegate
- composite

Code example:

```
   interface Vehicle {
        function canMove();
    }

    class TransportFleet implements Vehicle {

        private $vehicles;

        public function __construct(array $vehicles = array()) {
            $this->vehicles = $vehicles;
        }

        public function canMove() {
            foreach($this->vehicles as $vehicle) {
                if (! $vehicle->canMove() ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the *Composite* design pattern. In UML class diagram it looks as follows (which corresponds to your description):

[image: abstract composite class diagram]

**UPDATE 1:**

if you take a look at both class diagrams, you'll see that the second diagram matches the *composite* part of the first diagram, which is a generic illustration of the composite design pattern:

[image: composite class diagram]

Comment: good catch,i was about to answer it's not a specific pattern, i was too focus on how entities where named.

Comment: how does the leaf object fit in to the sample code i posted?

Comment: i have updated my answer to add a class diagramm corresponding to your description.